# Exact Place where Request.ValidateInput Function

Tags: asp.net

which is the Exact Place where Request.ValidateInput Function is calling during the ProcessRequest Phase..? (in asp.net 2.0)

Answer (score 0):

RequestValidation fires very early in the lifecycle.

These events & methods fire and then at the DeterminePostBackMode point the request is terminated.

- ExecuteStep
- Execute
- BeginProcessRequest
- ProcessRequestInternal
- ProcessRequestWithNoAssert
- ProcessRequest
- ProcessRequestMain
- DeterminePostBackMode

Here's an example stacktrace from a HttprequestValidationException.

```
at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String s, String valueName, String collectionName) 
at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateNameValueCollection(NameValueCollection nvc, String collectionName) 
at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form() 
at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm() 
at System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull) 
at System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode() 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
at ASP.register_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in d:\Temporary ASP.NET Files\belfast\09a30891\d8a3024a\App_Web_fxdlie1w.16.cs:line 0 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Thanks,

Phil.

Comment: can we access ValidateRequest value on CodeBehind..? That is my actual Requirement